# opencv using python - copy roi to new smaller image

Tags: python, opencv

In opencv using python - 
How can I create a new image that is simply a copy of an roi from another image?
Surely there is something along the lines of

```
Mat roi = img( Rect(x,y,w,h) );
```

for python, or anything more elegant than the brute force

```
rect=[x,y,w,h]
img = cv2.imread(subst)
roi= np.zeros((rect[3],rect[2],3),np.uint8)  #is this really reversed? who ordered that?
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(w+x,h+y),[255,0,0],thickness=1)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey()
#cv.Copy(cv.fromarray(img),cv.fromarray(roi),cv.fromarray(mask))  #can't make it work...
for x in range(rect[2]):
    for y in range(rect[3]):
        roi[y,x,:]=img[y+rect[1],x+rect[0],:]
```

and btw how do the x,y coordinates order - is it [x,y,c] or [y,x,c] to specify a point at x (horizontal) and y (vertical)? It seems like its [y,x,c], iiuc, while the cv2.rectangle is (x,y) and img.shape is (y,x) which would be even more annoying than (g,r,b) instead of (r,g,b)....

Comment: BTW your C++ above doesn't actually make a copy. Perhaps you meant `Mat roi = img(Rect(x, y, w, h)).clone();`

Comment: Have you tried `Mat roi = image[x : y, x + w : y + h]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import os
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(filename)
roi = img[row:row+height,column:column+width]
cv2.imshow('ROI',roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: This works assuming the image is grayscale.  You should probably add another accessor for the third dimension in case we have colour (i.e. `roi = img[x:x+w, y:y+h, :]`

Comment: It works on color images for me in Python 2.7.6 with or without the additional accessor.

Comment: Weird... I get an error.  Time to update my distro.  Thanks for the message!

Comment: still, should be : `img[y:y+h, x:x+w]` (that's a plain numpy roi, btw)

Comment: @berak, you're right, I've edited my answer to clarify and correct.