# How to split a video frame into 9 pieces?

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-processing

I am using Opencv2 in Python3.
I'm writing "shot boundary detection" program for news videos.
 
I've just need to split a video frame into 9 pieces for the beginning. But, i'm not sure how to do that cus i'm new in this field. I did it with cropping but it seems to me that it is not right thing to do to split a frame into pieces.

Note: When i search with "my title", i couldn't reach the ROI answer. But it now seems that this is ROI.

Comment: So it's like if you had 9 cameras and you and to show all images in a single frame, right?

Comment: No its like if my one frame shape is 720x 240 I need to divide a frame 9 pieces like 240x80 and after that i'm gonna find local histogram for these 9 pieces. To simplify more, you can think like not frame but image, i guess.

Comment: The thing you re looking for is ROI. You can refer to the question asked on SO [Copy ROI with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734545/opencv-using-python-copy-roi-to-new-smaller-image)

Comment: Because of i am newbie in video processing. I didn't know the name in literature, btw when i search with my title i couldn't reach roi answer; until you wrote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use ROI's and add the different images in an array for example.

I tested with my cat:

[image]

Here you have the code: (Press key 'q' to finish it)

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
n_rows = 3
n_images_per_row = 3

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    height, width, ch = frame.shape

    roi_height = height / n_rows
    roi_width = width / n_images_per_row

    images = []

    for x in range(0, n_rows):
        for y in range(0,n_images_per_row):
            tmp_image=frame[x*roi_height:(x+1)*roi_height, y*roi_width:(y+1)*roi_width]
            images.append(tmp_image)

    # Display the resulting sub-frame
    for x in range(0, n_rows):
        for y in range(0, n_images_per_row):
            cv2.imshow(str(x*n_images_per_row+y+1), images[x*n_images_per_row+y])
            cv2.moveWindow(str(x*n_images_per_row+y+1), 100+(y*roi_width), 50+(x*roi_height))

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @cybseccrypt I improved the display code so that you don't have to drag the windows. Let me know if it works fine for you!